# Hide an LWC component based on custom property. (Set component visibility based on custom field in component)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-apps, lightning-app-builder

I have an LWC component on the Lightning App Builder. I saw that we can use "Set Component Visibility" feature to hide the component but it only works for standard Record/User/Permissions related fields. I want to hide the component dynamically from the flexipage based on custom property. I have also seen we could use "<template if:true>" or "<template if:false>" but that will still occupy the space on the flexipage.

Comment: What you have tried so far can you add the code and screenshot of the condition you are using?

Answer (score 0):

By "custom property" I assume you mean some property of the LWC itself rather than a custom field on your object. If so the only option is to wrap the template in a condition as you suggest at the end of your question. You are correct in saying this will leave a small additional vertical space where the component exists in the page but generally speaking this isn't particularly noticeable depending on the page layout.